Replace text does not work in document header
I use a document automation where the script replaces placeholders in document templates with user inputs fetched from Google Forms.
I realised that the placeholders in the header (identical with those in the body) are not replaced with the values (and the placeholders stay the same in the ready doc), however, in the body it runs flawlessly and everything is replaced as it should be.
The placeholders in my header were in a table cell and I thought that it was the issue, but when I tried with free text, it still didn't work.
I made sure that all placeholders match in the doc with that in the script, and as I said in the doc body it works perfectly.
This is the code snippet responsible for the task:
  const templateFile = DriveApp.getFileById(templateID);

  const copy = templateFile.makeCopy(fileName, responseFolder);
  const doc = DocumentApp.openById(copy.getId());

  var header = doc.getHeader();
  var body = doc.getBody();

  for (var key in values) {
  
    if (header) {
    header.replaceText(key, values[key]);
    }
    if (body) {
    body.replaceText(key, values[key]);
    }
  }

  doc.saveAndClose();



It would be very good for you to learn how to debug your code.
In the specific case of the code included in the question, you might have to create a function that emulates the form submission to pass the required parameters
Example
function test(){
  const templateId = /** Add here the template id */;
  const values = {
    key1: 'value 1',
    key2: 'value 2'
  };
  yourFunctionName(templateId, values)
}

Note: As the question doesn't include your complete function and enough details either, you should create the test function by yourself.
Then from the Apps Script Editor, set a break point on the line you would like to pause the execution to review the values assigned to the variables, then select test in the Editor dropdown, then click Debug.
Another option is to add Logger.log or console.log statements to print messages / the variable values to the execution log.
Related
About debugging

How to debug Google Apps Script (aka where does Logger.log log to?)

About replacing text in document header

Replace text in header of first page
Find and Replace text in entire Google Drive folder, headers, footers, google docs using a script


Many thanks for your reply. I am using logs to see what placeholders were replaced and with the body it works like a charm, but the header doesn't do anything. I also created a mock function to run and test the code which is just passing attributes to the replacetext function, and I still couldn't find a solution. I don't know if replace text in header is handled differently than in body?

Upd: I created a script with a brand new document, where I only placed placeholders in the header and in the body for test purposes. I ran the script and the placeholders were replaced with the provided values everywhere. Apparently, it's something to do with the google doc header settings which, so far, is beyond my knowledge.
